# Pasar valor de una variable Ajax PHP "undefined" mensaje

Tags: php, json, variables, undefined

estoy haciendo un sencillo envio de correo Electrónico, al enviarlo el mensaje de respuesta aparece como "undefined", he buscado cada una de las variables y no doy con la que debe estar definida, quizás sea el cansancio o mi falta de experiencia, y es en este preciso instante donde acudo por ayuda ala comunidad porque ya no se donde seguir buscando, acá dejo los códigos que utilizo, (cabe destacar que el envío funciona perfectamente, si alguien quiere hacer uso de el puede hacerlo, solo que deberia esperar la solución al mensaje de "Valor indefinido")

Archivo.js

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function () {

    //Desactivo el boton al darle click
    $("#submit_btn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#submit_btn span").text('Enviando');
    $("#submit_btn i").removeClass('d-none');

    var user_name = $('input[name=nombre]').val() + ' ' + $('input[name=apellido]').val();
    var user_email = $('input[name=email]').val();
    var user_phone = $('input[name=telefono]').val();
    var user_message = $('textarea[name=mensaje]').val();
    var user_destinatario = $('input[name=destinatario]').val();

    //simple validacion
    var post_data, output;
    var proceed = true;
    if (user_name == "") {
        proceed = false;
    }
    if (user_email == "") {
        proceed = false;
    }
    if (user_destinatario == "") {
        proceed = false;
    }

    if (user_message == "") {
        proceed = false;
    }
    //al estar todo bien...
    if (proceed) {

        //datos a ser enviados
        post_data = {
            'nombre': user_name,
            'email': user_email,
            'telefono': user_phone,
            'mensaje': user_message,
            'destinatario': user_destinatario
        };

        //datos post Ajax 
        $.post('contacto.php', post_data, function (response) {


            if (response.type == 'error') {
                output = '<div class="alert-danger" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:30px;">' + response.text + '</div>';
            } else {
                output = '<div class="alert-success" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:30px;">' + response.text + '</div>';

                //reseteo los valores de campos
                $('.contact-form input').val('');
                $('.contact-form textarea').val('');
            }

            $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();

            // activo el boton
            $("#submit_btn").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#submit_btn span").text('Enviar otro');
            $("#submit_btn i").addClass('d-none');

        }, 'json');

    }
    else {
        output = '<div class="alert-danger" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:30px;">Por favor complete los campos.</div>';
        $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();


        $("#submit_btn").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#submit_btn span").text('Enviar otro');
        $("#submit_btn i").addClass('d-none');
    }

});
```

con este envío los datos por correo
Contacto.php

```
<?php
$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['nombre']));
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$message = $_POST['mensaje'];
$telefono = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['telefono']));
$destinatario = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['destinatario']));
$from = "paginaweb.com";
$to = $destinatario;
$subject = "Web de la empresa";
$message = "Script en HTML";

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
$text = "Mensaje enviado";
echo json_encode($text);
die; ?>
```

desde acá recibo la información para el formulario "index.html"

```
<form class="contact-form" onsubmit="return false">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12" id="result"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder=" Nombre:" required="" id="nombre" name="nombre">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder=" Apellido:" required="" id="apellido" name="apellido">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder=" Email:" required="" id="email" name="email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="tel" placeholder=" Teléfono:" required="" id="telefono" name="telefono">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder=" Solicitud" required="" id="mensaje" name="mensaje"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12" >

                                    <span class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"><label><input type="radio" id="destinatario" name="destinatario" value="mail01@gmail.com" required ><strong> Opción 1</strong></label></span>

                                    <span class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"><label><input type="radio" id="destinatario" name="destinatario" value="mail02@icloud.com" checked><strong> opcion 2</strong></label></span>

                                    <span class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"><label><input type="radio" id="destinatario" name="destinatario" value="mail03@yahoo.com"><strong> opcion 3</strong></label></span>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-gradient btn-rounded mt-4" id="submit_btn"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin mr-2 d-none" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Contactar</span></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

y éste es un print de la página en el navegador
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradeciendo su ayuda y esperando su respuesta, me despido

Comment: Para más facilidad dinos dónde es que marca el undefined.

Comment: Gracias por contestar .. el mensaje me sale en el index.htm donde tengo mi formulariol

Comment: Sí, pero ¿qué archivo es ese (no queda claro en la pregunta)? ¿y, en qué línea?, por favor, revisa la consola de Javascript.

Comment: bueno me disculpo si no me se explicar. en mi archivo HTML, donde tengo mi formulario, aparecen las respuesta de las verificaciones, Ejemplo: "Por favor complete los campos." asi mismo si existe algun error, aparece un mensaje de error. bueno lo que debería pasar al enviar correctamente el correo es aparecer un mensaje: "Mensaje enviado" pero en vez de eso sale "undefined". NO Utilizo consola de Java. asi que no es en la consola es en el HTML del index

Comment: No me refiero a la consola de Java, sino de Javascript, que se activa en las opciones del navegador. De todos modos, con la imagen ya se sabe, más o menos, donde buscar. Tú intentas acceder a una propiedad `text` de `response`, la cual no existe, cambia esto en el servidor y prueba de nuevo: `$text = array("text"=>"Mensaje enviado"); echo json_encode($text);`, ahí sí la respuesta tendrá una clave `text` a la cual poder acceder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde el servidor debes emitir un JSON que tenga las claves que vas a evaluar en el `success` de la llamada Ajax. Actualmente estás evaluando las claves `type` y `text`, las cuales no existen ninguna.

Prueba a modificar el PHP así:

```
//... sólo  pongo la parte a modificar, el resto queda igual
if ( mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers) ) {
    $text = array ("text"=>"Mensaje enviado");
} else {
    $text = array ("error"=>true, "text"=>"Mensaje no enviado");
}

header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($text);
```

Y, en el código Javascript modifica esto así:

```
        if (response.error) {
            output = '<div class="alert-danger" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:30px;">' + response.text + '</div>';
        } else {
            output = '<div class="alert-success" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:30px;">' + response.text + '</div>';

//Todo lo demás igual
```

Comment: Excelente..! todo perfecto .. Funcionó al 100%

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias ..!

Answer (score 0):

antes de limpiar tus post deberias de cachar si te estan llegando con un if(isset($_POST['dato'])) y con eso retornar un error, la otra es donde recibes tu response abajo de ahi poner un console.log(response); asi veras cuales la respuesta del servidor, por que parece que nunca te va a responder esto response.type debuguea un poco tu response

Comment: Gracias Cristhian probaré lo que dices y te comento

Comment: Ok comento. ya no tengo **response.type** porque lo cambie tal y como dijo @a-cedano. y con el `if(isset($_POST['dato']))` al inicio del php, Funciona muy bien, EXCELENTE gracias p[or sus colaboraciones